# FullCalender.js : How do i render a variable into a rendered template?

Tags: javascript

i am using full calendar js plugin to make a scheduling. and i want to have my own template when making some event. i coded like this :

```
        eventRender: function(event, element) { 

        var startTime = moment(event.time).format('h:mm');

        var endTime = moment(event.time).format('h:mm');

        var title = event.title;

        var newTemplate = '<div class="fc-content">'
                          //+'<div class="fc-header">
                          +'<span class="fc-time">startTime</span>'
                          //+'</div>'
                          +'<span class="fc-title">title</span>'
                          +'</div>';                          

        $(element).html(newTemplate);


    },
```

but what i get is instead of the value of the variable i always get the variable name displayed in my html. what seems to be wrong here? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

will be this?

```
var newTemplate = '<div class="fc-content">'
                          //+'<div class="fc-header">
                          +'<span class="fc-time">'+startTime+'</span>'
                          //+'</div>'
                          +'<span class="fc-title">'+title+'</span>'
                          +'</div>';
```

Comment: @jamesmafolyo jajaja,, where is my +1?=?, thanks to you

Comment: need to wait for several mins before i can check it :D here u go thanks